# HtAccess Change Extension Keep options

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

My problem is simple:

I want to change the page extension with htaccess:

`page.jpg?type=3&id=64` will look for `asd.php?type=3&id=64`

I tried with:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.html$ $1.php
```

but no succes.

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^(page)\.(png|gif|jpe?g)$ $1.php [L,NC]
```

Comment: I want only page.jpg => page.php, i see something with html in your answer

Comment: this throws me internal server error

i just want that page.jpg?options to go to page.php?options

page.php is a static page

Comment: That is exactly this rule is doing. It is internally rewriting `/page.jpg?options` to `/page.php?options`. For internal server error you will need to check Apache error.log since exact same rule worked for me in my Apache.

Comment: my mistake. thanks a lot ! the code works ! one little more request, can you make it for all image extensions ( jpg, jpeg, png and gif ) please?

Comment: If it worked out, you may mark the answer as accepted by clicking on tick mark on top-left of my answer.